# Adding a image button to a gridview header in c# with on click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, event-handling, onclick

I have a gridview (below) that populates with details about a project, I want to be able to sort the results by clicking on the header for which you want to sort by.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid"
PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" DataKeyNames="ProjectID"
OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" EnableModelValidation="True" Style="width: 95%;
float: left;" AllowSorting="True">
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Project Title" ItemStyle-Width="10%"
        ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true">
        <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Division" HeaderText="Division" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
        <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due Date" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
        <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
        <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
    </asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
<PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
```

To do this I add in my c# code, 2 image buttons to the header with an on click event added, I call this method in the page_load after the gridview is populated:

```
public void addHeaderFilters()
    {
        //Add to project title
        ImageButton titleAscImg = new ImageButton();
        titleAscImg.ID = "IMGB_ProjTitleAsc";
        titleAscImg.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(sortBy_Click);
        titleAscImg.ImageUrl = "images/image";
        titleAscImg.CssClass = "sortButton";

        ImageButton titleDescImg = new ImageButton();
        titleDescImg.ID = "IMGB_ProjTitleDesc";
        titleDescImg.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(sortBy_Click);
        titleDescImg.ImageUrl = "images/image2";
        titleDescImg.CssClass = "sortButton";

        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "Project Title ";

        GV_Projects.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Controls.Add(lbl);
        GV_Projects.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Controls.Add(titleAscImg);
        GV_Projects.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Controls.Add(titleDescImg);
    }

    public void sortBy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton imgb = new ImageButton();
        imgb = (ImageButton)sender;
    }
```

This displays the header as expected, however when I click on either image button, the event isn't fired and the header returns back to its default from the aspx code removing the arrows, and I'm not quite sure why?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Page Load Method:
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    addHeaderFilters();
}'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to encase the addHeaderFilters() in a !IsPostBack statement

Like this

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    addHeaderFilters();
}
```

Comment: this was my first thought also, but its within !IsPostBack

Comment: Is the grid binding method also contained within the !IsPostBack? Is the grid being rebound at all? If so, you will also have to rebind your header everytime you rebind your gridview.

Comment: I was binding it, as I had a gridview within it, and as far as I was aware I was rebinding the header too.

I changed my design around to make it more achievable and save time. I used a TemplateField with a HeaderTemplate within it, this allowed me to have the ImageButtons coded in the ascx page without having to add it dynamically - thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void GridViewTransaction_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        ImageButton btnExcelReport = new ImageButton();
        btnExcelReport.ID = "BtnExcelReport";
        btnExcelReport.ImageUrl = "images/excel.gif";
        btnExcelReport.ToolTip = "generate Excel report from result";
        btnExcelReport.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(btnExcelReport_Click);

        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(btnExcelReport);
    }
}
```